# Have two elements side by side fill all space vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two elements in my page's body that I want to live side by side and fill all vertical space.

My code is super simple:

```
<!-- index.html minus all the usual junk-->
<!-- also ignore the lack of a url-tag and the like, it's intentionally left out -->
<body>
  <textarea id="text-field">
  <iframe id="render-field">
</body>
```

and

```
// index.css
body {
  font: caption;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#text-field {
  font-family: Courier;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#render-field {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

It doesn't matter what I try, the two elements will not fill all the sapce available in the body.

Any help?

Comment: You have to give it a set height, like 100px. There's no height for a browser window, they just scroll. Or try vh and vw https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Give `height: 100%;` to `html`

Comment: @Alex that worked, thanks

Comment: But that alone won't work on all browsers if you don't use closing tags (see my answer below)

Comment: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: @Johannes doesn't matter, I'm using it for an Electron project. Browser compatibility is literally not a requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use closing tags.

Second, for height: 100%; you also need to apply that to the `html` tag to have a height reference for the `body` element. And also apply `margin: 0` to `html` and `body` to reset the default margin to zero:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font: caption;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#text-field {
  font-family: Courier;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#render-field {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="text-field"></textarea>
  <iframe id="render-field"><iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: why is resetting the default margin necessary?

Comment: as I wrote: Because all (or at least almost all, nut sure) browsers have a default margin (a few px) for the body element, which you only can get rid of that way. To see that default margin, just put a 100% wide DIV with a background color into an empty page: You'll see some space at all sides of the DIV due to that margin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plunker example using `vh`

> vh    Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NiJ7q7dtJncoQKHf1iYy?p=preview)

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)